# Accessible English Dictionary with words and and proper names

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I need a way to check whether a word does exist in english dictionary. THis word can be also a proper name (city's name, vip's name, location's name.. whatever), considering that also proper names will be lower cased.

What is the best database or dictionary I can access via Python without restrictions for doing this?

Comment: You can access pretty much any database you want in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
print requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search="+raw_input("Search For:").lower()+"&go=Go").content
```

probably isnt quite what you want ... but its something

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, the UIUC NER tagger contained a large list of entities derived from wikipedia.  You should be able to download their tagger from
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/download_view/NETagger
unpack it, and access the lists contained within via standard python methods of reading files.  If you are just looking to check whether a word is in a dictionary at all, you could use WordNet.

One issue that you will run into is how to deal with multi-token entities.  If you run across the Chinese premier's name, any single token from his name may not appear in a dictionary, but the full name should be recognized as a name.  In that case you will want a real NER system, like UIUC or Stanford NLP tools.  It will also be much more time-consuming, and you will have to consider only textual references.